# C# Showing form in Thread is not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want create loading screen until the opening new form. I have three form.

1- Login Panel
2- Loading Gif Form
3- Main Menu

When user going to Main Menu this process is at least 2 seconds. I must show loading gif to user in this time. My code is here;

```
         formLoading form_loading = new formLoading();      
         private void formLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       form_loading.Show();
       form_loading.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form_loading.Visible = true;
        OpeninFunction();
    }

    public void OpeninFunction()
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        fy.Show();
        fy.Visible = true;
        Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();
        this.Hide();
        Thread tr = new Thread(openMainForm);
        tr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        tr.Start();  
    }

    public void openMainForm()
    {
        formMain fas = new formMain(guncelleme);  
        fas.Visible = true;
        fas.Show();
    }
```

This code looks like smooth. But when i use btnLogin -> Loading gif is showing screen. And MainForm is coming and going. I can see 0.3 sec. 
I'm doing something related to thread wrong?

Thanks from now.

If this is not possible, I'm open to your suggestions.

Comment: You need to open the new form in the UI thread.  You don't need to create a new thread to call `openMainForm()`.

Comment: Call is illegal, it will lead to `InvalidOperationException` due to Cross Thread   referencing of the Ui components